# X11 networking on linux

Tags: linux, x11

I know you can connect to a remote X11 server to use them like a local X11 system.

My question is: Can you connect multiple computers to work together and display (through their videos outputs) an unique instance of X11 desktop?

Or, another phrasing: Can you process and display an image using several X11 servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Distributed Multihead X Project](http://dmx.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

X11 is a protocol. If you use it over the network, the GUI application that you run remotely, actually connects to your local X11 server. So yes, you can have multiple clients running applications on the server that display on different X11 servers. As for processing images using X11 server - what do you actually mean by that? The only thing comes to mind is multiple monitors. If so, then yes - you can use a dedicated X11 server per monitor.

Comment: Ok, i understand, but i have another question: Those "display servers" can work together to display only one big desktop? For instance: having two display servers, can one of them display only a half of the desktop and the other one display the other half?

Comment: @Alvaro: Yes and no. X11 don't display "desktops", X11 renders application's GUI. What appears to you as a "desktop" is a set of many small GUI applications like task launcher etc. You can display each application on separate X11 server while they will appear to you as unified "desktop" environment. Though it doesn't make much sense from technical point of view.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to have multiple computers collaborate on displaying a single X11 display. This is not directly possible.

However, you *can* have multiple video cards in a single computer and use the [Xinerama extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinerama) to have the multiple cards show a single logical X server. This can allow you to use a single machine to drive several monitors with ease. (With video cards that support multiple outputs, you ought to be able to get up to four or six monitors without *too* much hassle. Dozens might be very difficult.)

I can't think of any mechanism that would allow a single keyboard and mouse to reliably work across multiple monitors driven by multiple computers. But if your problem is significantly restricted (if it really is just viewing an image via several X servers), then you could write a client application that renders only a portion of the image and run multiple clients that each display only a portion of the image -- that when taken together, looks like the image is seamlessly displayed by several systems simultaneously. This is definitely a bit awkward though, as the coordination of the system will require some thought.

Comment: "I can't think of any mechanism that would allow a single keyboard and mouse to reliably work across multiple monitors driven by multiple computers." [I can.](http://synergy-foss.org/)

Comment: "... you want to have multiple computers collaborate on displaying a single X11 display. This is not directly possible..."

That's exactly my question. So, there's no way to do that. Damn! The only way is using multiple video card in one computer... I thought the X11 had the answer...

Comment: @Alvaro: Ignacio posted a link to http://synergy-foss.org/ which claims that it can do this -- or something very similar. It'd be well worth investigating!

Comment: @sarnold: AFAIK Synergy only manage the input (keyboard and mouse) through several computers. My problem is: have "... multiple computers collaborate on displaying a single X11 display..."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drag windows from one screen to another, or display a part of a window here and another part of it there, then no, this is not possible with existing out-of-the-box software. You can try to modify a "virtual" X server such as [Xephyr](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr) such that it uses multiple backend X servers for portions of its framebuffer. This is not exactly trivial but should be much easier than writing your own multi-box X server from scratch.

If you want to clone one desktop to many displays connected to different computers, you can try running VNC or RDP clients on all displays but one.